# Change the value of a number in the element style

Tags: javascript, html

My friends, I want to change the red fill percentage number with JavaScript code,
for example, I want the red color to be filled to the percentage given in Input 1.
I have a code that does not work and I do not know how to fix the problem

```js
function change(){

var test = document.getElementById("in1").value;

document.getElementById("in1").style = " height:8px;      background: linear-gradient(to left, red test %, #e0e0e0 0%) right       bottom / 200% 100%;      width: 50%;      float: left; "
alert(test)
}
```

```html
<div class="hn" style="height: 8px;width: 98%;margin: 7px;">
   
  <div id="left-me" 
  style=" height:8px;
      background: linear-gradient(to left, red 10%, #e0e0e0 0%) right 
      bottom / 200% 100%;
      width: 50%;         
      float: left;">
    </div>
  <div id="right-me" 
  style="height: 8px;
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #32c538 58%, #e0e0e0 0%) right        
   bottom / 200% 100%;
   width: 50%;
   float: left;">
  
</div>

</div>

input1 : <input id="in1" value="51" onchange="change()">% </input>
```

Comment: `test` inside `""` is considered a literal string.  It is not using the variable.  To use the variable you either have to use concatenation, or switch to a template literal and use interpolation.

Comment: yes. it work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did small amendment to your code. Have a look. There was a one mistake, which is you took the wrong element. and if you want to use variable inside a string,

```
let test = `some string ${value} rest string`
```

```js
function change() {
            var test = document.getElementById("in1").value;
            var t = `height:8px; background: linear-gradient(to left, red ${test}%, #e0e0e0 0%) right bottom / 200% 100%; width: 50%; float: left;`;

            document.getElementById("left-me").style = t
        }
```

```html
<div class="hn" style="height: 8px;width: 98%;margin: 7px;">

        <div id="left-me" style=" height:8px;
            background: linear-gradient(to left, red 10%, #e0e0e0 0%) right 
            bottom / 200% 100%;
            width: 50%;         
            float: left;">
        </div>
        <div id="right-me" style="height: 8px;
         background: linear-gradient(to right, #32c538 58%, #e0e0e0 0%) right        
         bottom / 200% 100%;
         width: 50%;
         float: left;">

        </div>

    </div>

    input1 : <input id="in1" value="51" onchange="change()">% </input>
```